# Referenced System.Net.Http assembly is not copied to the output bin\Release catalog on dotnet msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following project configuration:

1) `Project1`: .NET Framework 4.6.1 project

2) `Project2`: .NET Standard project with `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>`

3) `Project3`: .NET Standard project with `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>`

So, `Project3` references `System.Net.Http`. `Project2` references `Project3` and `Project1` references `Project2`.

When I build any configuration in Visual Studio 2017 the `Project1\bin\%Configuration%\` directory contains `System.Net.Http.dll` as well as other `System` assemblies.

Also I can see that the following binding redirect is generated in `Project1.exe.conf`:

`<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
</dependentAssembly>`

When I use `dotnet msbuild` to build (navigate to the solution folder and use the following command: `dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Release`) everything builds successfully but the `System.Net.Http` dll is missing from the same directory.

When I run the application outside of the Visual Studio I get the following error during runtime: `Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2`.

Why? How do I use the `dotnet msbuild` tooling to ensure all referenced assemblies are copied?

Update: my `dotnet` version is `2.1.2`.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the `dotnet` SDK is being used on command line? `dotnet --version` should tell. It should be at least `2.1.2` to behave the same as the current VS 2017 version.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue according to your steps, I created a class library project1 with .net framework 4.6.1 and reference project2 with multiple frameworks netstandard2.0;net461. But after build in Visual Studio, only project2.dll in the `project1\bin\%Configuration%\` directory. How  did your Project3 references System.Net.Http, use nuget? Does your project2 also reference  `System.Net.Http`? If you can provide a sample to us will be better.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT My `dotnet` version is `2.1.2` My `Project3` references `System.Net.Http` using NuGet, version of the package is `4.3.3`. What I also found is that the following binding redirect gets generated in `Project1.exe.conf` file: `<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />`. Basically, the debugging runs fine in Visual Studio but when I run the application elsewhere I get the `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2` error

Comment: @PhilP., thanks for your detailed reply. But after build solution in VS, the folder `Project1\bin\%Configuration%\` directory only contains `Project2.dll`. There must be somewhere I did wrong, so could you please share me some more detail steps to reproduce this issue? Or share me a simple sample via onedrive. Besides, since you project1 is a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project, have you try to build it with `MSBuild` not `dotnet`?

Comment: @PhilP. having the same problem.  Only resolution so far was to roll back VS to older version.  Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT - please see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821894/vs-2017-release-15-5-1-project-reference-to-system-net-http-unresolved

Comment: Have you try to install the nuget package `System.Net.Http` with the version 4.1.0 to the project1? Or update the package `System.Net.Http` for project to the version 4.1.0?

Comment: my 2 cents: I found that the same Nuget package had two different versions of the same DLL on two different machines. My dev machine recieve dll 4.1.1 and our build server received 4.1.0. Try clearing your Nuget cache.

Answer (score 1):

There is something strange that happens with System packages that are added as nuget references. There should be no need to add System libraries as packages, they should exist on the host, but in a few cases, it is necessary, I think a similar issue exists with System.Runtime.Caching related to version conflicts.

I think the problem is that since the library is in the GAC, the build system ignores copying it to the output assuming that it is present and available without needing to be packaged.

Visual Studio, as you might imagine, behaves by its own rules which is really annoying because it is hard to see why the problem is happening.

To be extra annoying, I can't quite remember what I had to do to fix it. I might have uninstalled the library from the GAC, set the reference properties Copy Local to be true (if not already) or possibly referenced the dll directly from the SDK location on disk (with copy local = true) and not use the nuget package at all.