# Using mimekit nuget package (via paket) in common project removes existing System.net.http.dll from other projects referencing common project

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I had added a new reference of mimekit library (added mimekit and mailkit via paket) in common project used by several other projects.

To use mimekit I used below code:

using MimeKit; namespace Project.Common.Email.Interfaces { public interface IMailKitBody { BodyBuilder BodyBuilder { get; set; } } }

But while building the complete solution after adding above file, System.net.http.dll is getting removed from one of the dependent projects having reference of common project and another project which actually have a reference of System.net.http.dll.

And as soon as I remove this file from Common then System.net.http.dll starts appearing in the dependent project.

Could anyone help me out how this problem be resolved?

I know Mimekit is dependent upon System.net.http.dll and it could conflict with existing one in dependent projects. I have already tried following things: -removing System.net.http.dll reference from common -Setting Copy Local property of DLL to True -Adding reference System.net.http.dll from package folder

System.net.http.dll should be present in dependent project.

Comment: Looks like this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782412/referenced-system-net-http-assembly-is-not-copied-to-the-output-bin-release-cata

Comment: it looks similar issue but originating source is different, I am using same build method in both cases with Mime or without Mime, but without mime system.net.http is coming along while in other one it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to MailKit 2.1.5.1 to fix this issue.